# How to run gwan with python in virtual environment?

Tags: python, virtualenv, g-wan

My python script is as below

```
#!~/PyEnv/bin/python

import sys
import my_lib

print 'hello'
# do something with my_lib
my_lib()

sys.exit(200)
```

I placed it in /csp folder with name 'hello.py'. When I connected to "localhost:8080/?hello.py", I received a message "ImportError: No module named my_lib".

Because this script didn't run with python in virtualenv. How can I resolve it ?

Answer (score 1):

This should be a problem with the local path. VirtualEnv is just a setup tool that can generate local python environment. This is used a lot for isolating a project from the system python.

I think that when you use the path ~/PyEnv/bin/python, then this version of python doesn't automatically redirect import requests to ~/PyEnv/lib.

This is some PATH issue and I am not sure if G-WAN should necessarily address this :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to narrow the cause of the problem:

- Does the G-WAN Python example run fine WITHOUT `virtualenv`?
- Does the G-WAN Python example run fine WITH `virtualenv`?
- Does your script work without `virtualenv`?

If the latter is true then you might need to investigate what `virtualenv` is doing.

Comment: If I link /usr/bin/python to ~/PyEnv/bin/python, this error is disappeared.

Comment: Thank you for the "fix". You should write it as a "solution" and accept YOUR solution to let other Python users find it easier.